# Trouble in dueling with loader loading the same thing twice

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, programming-languages, loading, external

I have a background symbol that does the loading external jpg job, and a engine as3 that loops 2 backgrounds continuously on the screen. However, only one background can load file although they "new" from the same symbol. To test this urr... phenomenon, I exchange the order of "new" code of 2 backgrounds, then whichever on top will perfectly load the jpg file and the other will remain blank.
has anyone faced this problem before? or knowing how to solve it? plz teach me. this external loading is really painful to me from the beginning.

For the code: (because it is very very basic so I think I could neglect it; sorry for the inconvenience)

Background code

```
var URLvar:URLRequest;
var fBGLoader : Loader = new Loader( );
URLvar = new URLRequest( "background collection/fyrise/fyriseFront.png" );
fBGLoader.load(URLvar);
this.addChild(fBGLoader);
```

Engine code

```
private var B1:fBG;
private var B2:fBG;
private var Container= new MovieClip();
BLen=2500;
B2=new fBG();
B1=new fBG();

B1.x=0;
B1.y=0;
B2.x=B1.x-BLen;
B2.y= B1.y;
Container.addChild(B1);
Container.addChild(B2);
stage.addChild(Container);
```

so as you can see, I put the B2 = new fBG() prior to  B1=new fBG(), then I can see B2 but not B1 and if I exchange the order, I can see B1 but not B2. That's the problem!

Comment: What is T_T? And please add some related code. Otherwise its difficult to guess the problem.

Comment: Can you post a chunk of the code that you're using to load and loop?

Comment: I has added the code, plz help me to solve this problem. thx

Comment: Where do you add B1 and B2 to the stage?

Comment: below those code. Sorry, I forgot to add those.

Comment: pls work on your coding style: don't start variables with uppercase-characters - use camelCase instead. makes it 100% easier to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you loading the image twice or just once?  If you load the image once and use it for both fBG objects you would get that problem since Bitmap objects can only have a single parent (the last addChild(fBGLoader) is the only one working, the first one will be cancelled by the later one).

To fix this, you need to make sure that both fBG objects have their own Bitmap instance (they can however share the same BitmapData).  So wherever you are doing :

```
this.addChild(fBGLoader);
```

Do this instead :

```
var img : Bitmap = Bitmap(fBGLoader.content);
this.addChild(new Bitmap(img.bitmapData));
```

This will make sure that each fBG object has it's own set of coordinates and information to display the background image.

Comment: if you load images via the Loader class you don't have to mess with Bitmap or BitmapData classes/objects - at least not, if you just want to display them.

Comment: Thank you, but it said TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake in the code, it's not the loader but the content of the loader that needs to be typecasted.  I'll update the answer

Comment: As for Loading the images twice, it's true that this will work because it will create 2 Bitmaps in the background.  However, you do have to wait twice as long to load the same image which is not very ideal (especially not for web deployed apps).

Comment: So do you know anyway I could duplicate it after load it? Since my situation is exactly same as what you describe above. Thank you a lot!

Comment: create a loader queue, then when you try to load the image a second time, it'll already be cached. or you a loader class that takes care of this: http://apdevblog.com/examples/apdev_preloader/

Comment: I have updated the code above to allow you to duplicate it.  In your case, since you aren't changing the image, you can simply make new Bitmap objects that have the same bitmapData (this is what my code does).

Answer (score 0):

i put together a small example over at wonderfl: http://wonderfl.net/c/1dze

i just try and load the same image twice - and it works. here is the code:

```
package {
  import flash.net.URLRequest;
  import flash.display.Loader;
  import flash.display.Sprite;
  public class FlashTest extends Sprite {

     private var loader1:Loader;
     private var loader2:Loader;

     public function FlashTest() {
        loader1 = new Loader();
        loader2 = new Loader();
        loader2.x = 40;
        loader2.y = 40;

        loader1.load(new URLRequest("http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_zqzgnaU9IiE/TIuSdJyuWsI/AAAAAAAAAA0/4qVZxO503vE/s1600/fat+cat.jpg"));
        loader2.load(new URLRequest("http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_zqzgnaU9IiE/TIuSdJyuWsI/AAAAAAAAAA0/4qVZxO503vE/s1600/fat+cat.jpg"));
        addChild(loader1);
        addChild(loader2);
     }
  }
}
```

the problem has to be somewhere else in your code.

maybe try changing the position of the movieclips first to see if both are loaded - like i did in the code above.

**edit**

you could also put this into two classes like so:

```
package {
  import flash.display.Sprite;

  public class FlashTest extends Sprite {
    private var bgLoader1:BGLoader;
    private var bgLoader2:BGLoader;

    public function FlashTest() {
        bgLoader1 = new BGLoader();
        bgLoader2 = new BGLoader();
        bgLoader2.x = 40;
        bgLoader2.y = 40;
        addChild(bgLoader1);
        addChild(bgLoader2);
    }
  }
}
```

and then

```
package {
  import flash.display.Loader;
  import flash.display.Sprite;

  public class BGLoader extends Sprite {
    private var loader:Loader;
    public function BGLoader() {
        loader = new Loader();
        loader.load("URLTOIMAGE");
        addChild(loader);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: yup, It works because you have 2 loader, but I only have one in the background symbol. i just new this symbol 2 times in the main AS, and it's seen to be cannot duplicate the load code inside the background symbol. Thank you a lot, maybe I have 2 make 2 symbol for two new code for good. T_T

Comment: then you also got two loaders ... :(

Comment: ?? I only got 1 in the background code : fBGLoader.load(URLvar)

Comment: but you create 2 instances of this class - so you got two seperate loader instances as well

Comment: i hope it works as what you said but... It's seen to not create a another instance just by new it 2 times in the main as. thank you ^^

Comment: o.o It works when I test in another flash file. but it seem very similar to mime. maybe you were right. Something wrong with my code. Thank you a lot for your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Is the "background code" the `fBG` class? And if so, is that code being run in the constructor? If so, I think your solution should work. But it's hard to say without seeing a bit more context.

You should be able to load the same image twice and not have a problem. So my guess is that your issue is revolving around how you've set up your classes (e.g. the context I mentioned before). I'm guessing you've got some other issue there that isn't shown in the code you've provided.

As an aside, you don't really need two separate loaders if you just want two of the same image. You could just load the image once and then use the Bitmap classes to create a copy of the Loader's content.

Oh, and on second look, your statement:

```
BLen=2500;
```

won't work. You need something like:

```
var BLen:Number = 2500;
```

Comment: Thank you a lot and sorry, i didn't copy my code properly from the as file. I did var it before. Everything worked perfectly just before I change from using instance inside my flash file to loading external file. I think my situation is like what Godfather described above. Please help me to solve this problem. thank a lot.

Comment: Well, in that case we definitely need to see more about how your files are structured. If the code you posted worked before, that seems to indicate that something else you've done (how you've organized your classes, what the files look like, etc.) is the problem. I'd recommend you post more info about what each file looks like (or how your FLA is structured, if you're not using external .as class files).

Answer (score 0):

One of your instances is at -2500 px x coordinate on the screen, if I read your code correctly.  Is it possible that the graphic is loading, but because it is so far to the left of the viewport, you can't see it?

Also, I agree with some of the other posters that it is probably better to only load the file once, then duplicate it.  You can find out more about techniques for doing this here: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/blitting_mc.html.

HTH;

Amy